# vertical space between figures in one column

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats

I want to merge 3 images into one figure in one column. How can I control the vertical space between figures? I want to have no space or negative space (overlap) between the figures.

Note: I want different amount of space between figures. For example no space between 1st and 2nd image and 1cm space between 2nd and 3rd image. And `tabular` is not necessary.

Code I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't need the tabular, just a blank line between each image

Comment: why omit `p` from the `figure` option? (I added back in my answer)

Comment: In case of overlapping, think about using tikz and add opacity (Just an idea that may  be you didn't thought and could like). Also ,you have full and easy access to all of the positioning options you can imagine

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \setlength\lineskip{0pt}

    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}

    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}

    \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is I want different amount of space between the figures? I tried to set ` \setlength\lineskip{10pt}` however this chage space for both figures!

Comment: @cNinja what you said was that you wanted no space, however if you want to add some back then then before each figure you can add after the blank line `\vspace{2cm}` or whatever space you want.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image} \\[1cm]

    \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* have them in a tabular environment you can add

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
```

before the `\begin{tabular}` to remove the space between the images.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: great. However in this case I will have same space between all the figures. I want to have different space between the figures. And not necessary using tabular.